# Web Api response depending of parameter request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I would like to create a web api project and the response depend of  request  "apiVesion" parameter. How could I return the response depending of that parameter? For example:

if the apiVersion = 1 return /controllers/v1/response.cs

then if the apiVersion = 2 return /controllers/v2/response.cs

Is there any other way like Areas or routing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do that on the side that is calling the API? check before you send a request to the API?

Comment: You are right, but I can't handle the request. I'm receiving a request with appVersion = 1 or appVersion = 2

Comment: Ok, well just receive the request, check the AppVersion, and redirect it to whatever method you want depending on the version.

Comment: Is there any other way like Areas or routing?